# Item hover shows hidden text of all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I'm using this script to animate/show the hidden text of the item:

```
/* Artworks Hide/show text */
$(".item").hover(function() {
    //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
$(".item .art_title").fadeIn(200);
    }, function () {
//fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
    $(".item .art_title").fadeOut(200);
});
```

And this is the HTML:

```
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/artwork1.jpg" alt="artwork1" width="240" height="173">
                <div class="art_title">
                    <p>SWEET LIFE</p>
                </div>
                <div class="mask"></div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that when I hover over one item, it displays the hidden text of all itmes! How can I fix to display just the text of the item i'm hover?

Comment: Please add the (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML mark-up to your question, otherwise once the problem is solved the question will become useless to others.

Comment: I added it :), sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to `$(this).find(".art_title").fadeIn(200);`
and correspondingly, `$(this).find(".art_title").fadeOut(200);`

You are currently selecting all elements with class art-title. You want all elements within the hovered one that have class art-title.

Comment: 'children' would be better, because it's only one level down.

Comment: I find the more general the scope of your solution, the more people can use it when they come here off google. It is a coincidence that the targets are one level down. If he had used the selector ".item > .art_title" in his problem statement I could see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* Artworks Hide/show text */
$(".item").hover(function () {
    //fadein second image using jQuery fadeIn 
    $(this).find('.art_title').fadeIn(200);
}, function () {
    //fadein first image using jQuery fadeIn
    $(this).find('.art_title').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using classes for selectors in your jQuery code. You could also try:

```
$('.item').mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).find('.art_title').fadeIn(200); 

}).mouseleave(function() {

    $('.art_title').fadeOut(200);
});
```